# Add / Remove div class from link - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've played around on here enough to get this to where it is now, but I need a little help getting over the hurdle... like everyone I suppose!

I'm trying to make it so when you click a link (.clickable) it changes the width from span3 to span6.

The .clickable link is inside of a div, which is the one the class needs changed - .block is what I'm using in isotope for the item selector.

The link:

```
<a class="clickable" href="#enlarge-article"><i class="icon-fullscreen"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Enlarge</strong></a>
```

Javascript :

```
var $container = $('#portfolio');   
$container.delegate( '.block', 'click', function(){
      $(".block").removeClass('span3').addClass('span6').siblings().removeClass('span6').addClass('span3');
  $container.isotope('reLayout');
});
```

*updated class typo - is as appears in .js now*

Comment: jQuery delegate is an outdated function. see http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: if you want the `click` to work on `.clickable` why are you delegating `click` event to `.block` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $container = $('#portfolio');   
$container.delegate( '.block', 'click', function(){
    $(".block").removeClass('span6').addClass('span3');
    $(this).removeClass('span3').addClass('span6');
    $container.isotope('reLayout');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You said that the handler is for .clikable elements right ..

Also use `.on()`  instead of `.delegate()`

Try this

```
var $container = $('#portfolio');   
$container.on( 'click','.clickable', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // If you want to affect all the .block divs
    $(".block").removeClass('span6').addClass('span3');
    // If you want to affect only the block in which the anchor was clicked
    //$(this).closest('.block').removeClass('span6').addClass('span3');
    $(this).removeClass('span3').addClass('span6');
    $container.isotope('reLayout');
});
```

Comment: `$(this).parents('.block')` can be used if you dont want other `.block` elements affected

Comment: Yup thats true.. I will use the closest selector instead.. Edited post

Comment: I tried all of these, they all worked differently, but pckill below gave the right solution.